# ng serve angular app error using angular-cli

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

I am facing this error while trying to ng serve angular2 app using angular-cli on server.It is just the basic angular2 app without any changes.
[error details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epenE.png)

The Header Tab:
[Header Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPZMm.png)

Any help is appreciated.

Just adding --prod solve the problem: ng serve --host ip --prod

Comment: can you describe what `call` is actually? is it an object used within a class?

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you offered a little more information.

It could be a number of things. For example:

- If you are making HTTP requests, it could be a CORS problem.
- It could also be a network problem. This is a common error if you're internet connection is poor.

Comment: I think the problem that causes this error is that the file is so big so it takes too much time to load about 7.05 s.